# How to redirect to the Login View automatically when the session is time out in ASP.NET MVC 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session

guys! 
I am developing a ASP.NET MVC 3.0 project these days, but I don't know how to redirect to the Login View automatically when the session is time out. Someone told me try to code a customer Action filter class just like "SessionExpireFilterAttribute" in the Global.asax.cs file, indeed, it works well, but I have to add the Label "[SessionExpireFilter]"  to every Action should be concerned.So I don't think it's a good solution.Is there any one else give another better solution to make it works automatically! Thanks in advance！

Comment: The [Authorize] attribute on the "protected" controller/actions works out of the box with the default membership provider.  What session/membership provider are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action filters *do not have to be applied to every action* in order to work.

You can add the attribute at **controller level** and this will be applied to all actions within that controller.

See: [Understanding Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

An abstraction step further would be to add the attribute to a "BaseController" which all of your controllers inherit from.

Action filters are the standard way to implement this functionality in ASP.NET MVC.